# Is there a way to make a prezi and then convert it somehow to get it in html and css type code

Tags: javascript, html, css, impress.js, prezi

I am trying to make a website using impress .js but it is very long to get what i want. I realized prezi is the same thing.

Using embed show that it is done from prezi.
I would like to know if there is a way around this and I can get the actual code in html and css file type thing

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: No.

Prezi uses Flash and doesn't offer any export functionality to HTML & CSS. So there isn't a way to get to access the data. For basic impress.js presentations [strut.io](http://strut.io/) might help you.

Comment: is it possible from strut to get the code ? how do i put it on my website without it showing its from strut ?

Comment: @user3002308 Just preview your presentation and then save the site from your browser to your disk.